# Building out Salesforce App that calls API and parses results into table

Tags: rest, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am looking to build out something in Salesforce and I am not sure where to start. Essentially, what I am trying to do is:

- Click button on an account (or contact) object
- Once button is clicked, details from that record (e.g. name, address, etc.) are gathered and used as headers in an API call
- API call returns JSON that has details I want to parse into an editable table that is then attached to that record

I do not where to start with this. I have already done something similar with JavaScript and HTML via a Chrome extension but I don't know where to start with Salesforce. Could someone point me in the right direction?

I have tried looking over Salesforce developer docs but am having trouble piecing everything together

Comment: Have you seen my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/63364119/313628 ?

Answer (score 0):

Lightning Web Components (LWC) are a way for you to get started pretty quickly with a development focused solution, since you already have some familiarity with Javascript. Create a 'Account Quick Action button' and a LWC, to present a modal form for the User (similar to your chrome ext), and perform the API call in a promise/custom APEX method. An APEX controller class would be able to perform data update/data table display with the JSON response. Salesforce Trailhead content has many examples of these types of configurations.

Comment: Please declare your affiliation with it